# How to resolve a transaction error in Android?

Tags: java, android

I think my issue is about the version that I use for the the FragmentTransaction but I can't get it. Here is the message that I get when building app fails:

> Error:(21, 20) error: no suitable method found for add(int,BlankFragment)
>   method FragmentTransaction.add(Fragment,String) is not applicable
>   (argument mismatch; int cannot be converted to Fragment)
>   method FragmentTransaction.add(int,Fragment) is not applicable
>   (argument mismatch; BlankFragment cannot be converted to Fragment)
>   Error:(22, 20) error: no suitable method found for add(int,Fragment2)
>   method FragmentTransaction.add(Fragment,String) is not applicable
>   (argument mismatch; int cannot be converted to Fragment)
>   method FragmentTransaction.add(int,Fragment) is not applicable
>   (argument mismatch; Fragment2 cannot be converted to Fragment)
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>   Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Code:

```
package com.example.mohamedremih.fragments;

import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BlankFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener{
        Fragment2 fragment2;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        fragment2=new Fragment2();
        BlankFragment blankFragment=new BlankFragment();
        FragmentManager manager=getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction=manager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.lay1,blankFragment);
        transaction.add(R.id.lay2,fragment2);
        transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You've not explained any sort of problem. How are we supposed to help you if you don't tell us what's wrong in the first place? It's your job to clearly explain the problem you're having; that's the first half of a **question and answer**. If you don't properly write a question, we can't provide an answer. Please spend some time taking the [tour] and reading through the [help] pages, especially [ask]. When you say **the error**, you need to tell us **what error** you're getting, including the exact error message.

Comment: If you are getting an error then please post your logcat. Crank-up the old debugger and let us know at which line your program is failing.

Comment: Error:(21, 20) error: no suitable method found for add(int,BlankFragment)
method FragmentTransaction.add(Fragment,String) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; int cannot be converted to Fragment)
method FragmentTransaction.add(int,Fragment) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; BlankFragment cannot be converted to Fragment)
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Comment: these are the error messages that I get

Comment: The problem seems to be that the methods you are using to add the fragments does not recognize "BlankFragment" or "Fragment2" to be `Fragments`.  Please check that they are indeed `Fragments`. As a beginner you should get accustom to reading the official Android documentation. Please refer to https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the method i use for updating the fragment to a new fragment. Assuming you have a placeholder fragment in place already as a FrameLayout.

```
protected void swapFragment(BaseFragment fragment, @Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        if (fragment.isVisible()) {
            return;

        }

        A35Log.v(TAG, "swapFragment( " + fragment.getClass().getSimpleName() + " )");
        Bundle currentFragBundle = fragment.getArguments();
        if (currentFragBundle == null && bundle != null) {
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);

        } else if (bundle != null) {
            fragment.getArguments().putAll(bundle);

        }


        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();

        //Make sure the requested fragment isn't already on the screen before adding it
        if (fragment.isAdded()) {
            if (fragment.isHidden()) {
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().show(fragment).commit();

            }

            A35Log.v(TAG, "Fragment was hidden, so removeFullScreen instead of replace");
            return;

        }

        mSelectedFragment = fragment;
        A35Log.v(TAG, "Replacing Active Fragment with " + fragment.getClass().getSimpleName());

        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragPlaceholder, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

    }
```

Give that a shot instead and make sure you have a layout named fragPlaceHolder or else update this method to point to your FrameLayout from your XML instead. I usually have this in a BaseActivity or similar for swapping fragments like for a drawer nav.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because you're trying to add a `Fragment` from support library which is extended from `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` with `android.app.FragmentTransaction`. So, You need to use FragmentTransaction from support library with:

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
```